# Passing parameters to nginx reverse proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm creating an nginx reverse-proxy and so far so good, but how can I configure the reverse proxy to accept url with variables/parameters? For example: In axios I'm making a get request to the following url:
axios.get('http://localhost:1115/post/'+123)
please note that 123 is a variable and can be anything where in my node server it is:

```
app.get('/post/:id', function(req,res)
```

How should I handle this in my nginx reverse-proxy config file?

My current config look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name mydeployedsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    #What should be added here so i can pass this url:
    # http://127.0.0.1:1115/post/123
}
```

So basically the question is how can parameters be mapped in the nginx like:
how to map this address  `mydeployedsite.com/post/{id}` ??

Thanks.

Comment: can you add `rewrite (.*)//+(.*) $1/$2 permanent;` inside the location /. I guess it may solve the issue

Comment: Setting location as "/" will forward all requests to http://127.0.0.1:5000 including virtual path and querystrings. Could you please provide more details?

Comment: I want to add another location like this: location / post/ id{
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/id;
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        } And ID is a variable

Comment: @marmahan Try this: location ~ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/ } Every request from "http://<yourdomain>/post/id" will forward to "http://127.0.0.1:5000/post/id".

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. my question is how paramters are mapped like if i want to send an address of mydeployedsite.com/post/{id} where id can be any number, what should i write in the conf file??

Comment: This parameter is mapped in nodejs app, "app.get('/post/:id', (req,res) => { console.log(req.params.id); });" Nginx just forward virtual path  to nodejs app.